# Express 4 Socket io 404

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

Read all of similar questions + read [docs](http://socket.io/docs/), no one helped me.

I see this error every time

`polling-xhr.js?bd56:250 
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LKlhoge 404 (Not Found)`

Code on server:

```
...
const server = global.server = express();
const httpServer = require('http').Server(server);
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("Socket Ready");
});
...
```

Code on Client:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const newSocket = io('http://localhost:3000/');// or io()
}
```

If some one had this problem, gim me the answer. Thanks.